# Play framework 2.3.8 mixed content in production mode

Tags: https, requirejs, playframework-2.3, mixed-content

I'm running an application in prod mode, getting multiple "mixed content" warnings since scripts are apparently requested trough unsecure http. Of course in dev mode this is not an issue.
Allowing the browser to access mixed content (https and http), warnings like the following can be found in the console:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://192.168.0.100:9443/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

I've read many post with similar issues, but I couldnt find any simple solution. This happened to be a problem in prior versions of play, but for 2.3.8 seems to be fully funcional. Don't really know, hope some of you does.

Answer (score 0):

This patch should do the work: on build.sbt, add this two lines:

> ```
> # at the beggining
> import RjsKeys._
> #...
> # at the end
> webJarCdns := Map("org.webjars" -> "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars")
> ```